# Prevent maven to copy dependencies to WEB-INF\lib folder

Tags: maven

I have this dependency in the pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

However although the scope is "test" the jars are still copied to the `WEB-INF\lib` folder:

```
src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib
```

Comment: If you have any jars being copied to `src/main/webapp/**`, then you're doing something wrong. You shouldn't have any jars outside your `target` directory. If you track that down, you might just stumble across what's making the test jars show up.

Comment: Are you using [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) somewhere? If so, can you post relevant snippet?

Comment: run mvn dependency:tree and let us know if it appears somewhere as a non-test sep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible scenarios here.

1) These dependencies are somewhere referenced (directly or not) with `compile` or `runtime` scope besides their `test`-scoped use. Then, this wider scope is effectively used to satisfy all the needs about them.

2) You do (maybe unconsciously) some dependency processing hacking using [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) or stuff like that that do this mess.

And one issue at the end: I assume that this `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` directory is in fact empty (possibly doesn't even exist) and it's your mistake. As @Ryan said in his comment, all the libs (and any other build artifact) should land at `target` directory.